# React Native value not being assigned

Tags: react-native

I am fairly new to react native, so not sure what subtlety is causing my value not to be assigned.

```
console.log("NEW VALUE", this.props.appConfig.forms["reg1"].lists[refKey].list[thisMinor[key]]);
let thisYear = this.props.appConfig.forms["reg1"].lists[refKey].list[thisMinor[key]];
console.log("thisYear", thisYear);
thisMinor[key] = thisYear;
console.log("thisMinor[key]", thisMinor[key]);
```

printing

```
NEW VALUE, "2017"
thisYear, "2017"
thisMinor[key], "1" (what I would expect to be the previous value)
```

even if I change the assignment to the hardcoded

```
thisMinor[key] = "2017";
```

I still get the previous value printed ("1")

react-native: 0.49.3

EDIT: 
I added the following lines when creating the object and am now able to assign the variable. I guess react will not copy the object fully, I assume just a reference, that can't be assigned too?? There are many cases where I have been able to assign new objects and modify values without doing this hard assignment, so not sure the actual issue but this is a solution if anyone comes across this.

```
let thisMinor = {};
thisMinor = Object.assign(thisMinor, regMinors[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this is a JavaScript matter, not exactly React Native. Just saying so next time you may ask with correct tags.

The case is your `thisYear` variable returns a string `2017`. I guess your `key` index is returning `2`, so when you try to access `thisYear[key]` in fact you are returning the index 2 of the string which value is `1`

```
'2' = 0
'0' = 1
'1' = 2
'7' = 3
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am assigning it to a javascript object at `key`, not in an array